# KDE Partition Manager fail, when cancelled very long boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, kde

Hello I am new to Linux.

Today I tried to split partition into two, but it failed. To my surprise it still works, and it seems none of space is missing, files also look like working good. What I realized is my boot takes twice or triple the time it used to before.

I used KDE Partition Manager.
I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I tried to update kernel.

I tried to look for solution, but found nothing that could be helpful for me.

Here is log: https://pastebin.com/dr1LuKJM

Weird stops appear at:

- 3.828552 (5s)
- 17.925456 (5s)
- 26.671729 (4s)
- 35.455456 (15s)
- 62.569196 (10s)
- 71.505896 (10s)
- 90.795079 (15s)
- 105.215249 (15s)
- 120.761918 (61s!)

Could anyone help me? I promise to never try to partition in my life again! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the easiest way out of this is to backup your data and reinstall. It never ends well if you abort a partition operation but it’s not that hard. If you want to learn set up virtual machine and try it in there. There are plenty of guides online and answered questions on here

Comment: Unless you misaligned you partitions (which would cause performance issues) your slow boot might be caused by other issues. So make sure partitions start at MiB boundaries. And gaps in dmesg are normal. Once kernel passes boot sequence to systemd, it starts loading various processes and there might be some time with nothing in dmesg.